# Status bar in landscape for iPhone X

Tags: ios, landscape, iphone-x

Is the status bar always hidden for iPhone X in landscape? It just won't display as before when testing in the simulator.

**Update**: No change with iPhone X simulator in Xcode 9.0.1.

Comment: I am not sure, but its the bug in iOS 11

Comment: I'm not sure it's a bug in iOS 11. The status bar is visible with the iPhone 8 (simulator). iOS 11.0.2 in both cases.

Comment: ya I am also seen , but the problem is only in iphone-x

Comment: I checked in simulator iPhone x all the in-built App hide status bar in landscape mode

Comment: OK so we can maybe "safely" assume that Apple's intention is to always hide status bar in landscape mode for iPhone X. It's not a "bug" then?

Comment: We can not say it is bug but might be hide for give more attractive look ? not  sure ;(

Comment: @Jonny - the bug report is filed : https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-13394

Comment: it seems hidden on purpose as the safe-area is smaller in landscape mode on iPhone X slightly – comparing to an iPhone 7/8 screen.

Comment: This is not specific to iOS 11 or the iPhone X. The status bar has been hidden in landscape on all iPhones/iPod touches since at least iOS 9.

Comment: Are you sure? I’ve used status bars without problem on iOS 9/10/11 so far on all known iPhones until iPhone X. That said I have not confirmed this problem with a real device yet. While not that likely, there is still the possibility of a mistake in iOS.

Comment: Xcode 9.0.1 was released with specific "fixes" for iPhone X simulator, but the status bar has not changed, which must mean the status bar is definitely gone. I don't think they missed this, this is on purpose.

Comment: On iOS 11 all devices except iPhone X respect prefersStatusBarHidden method of VC. iPhone X just ignores it. Something wrong with iPhone X.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm just gonna answer this for now since it seems like the comments from iPatel, Anbu.Karthik is on the spot.

***iPhone X seems to force the status bar to be hidden in landscape.***

At least Messages and Calendar of the default apps work this way. (All the other apps I tried actually crashes in the Simulator)

Comment: I am not sure its hidden or frame will be modified, give a some time I checking my self

Comment: see this the bug report is filed : https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-13394

Comment: I've confirmed this with a real device. The status bar is just always hidden in landscape.

Comment: Unfortunately this is probably not a bug and is intentional. I suppose we just need to get used to Apple making these sorts of decisions on our behalf.